# I need to decode a encoded js

Tags: javascript

I downloaded an html theme that has a encoded piece of javascript at the end of the jquery file. I need to know how to decode it please

this is the code:

```
[]['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](self['\x75\x6e\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65']('%69%66%28%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%70%72%6f%74%6f%63%6f%6c%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%68%74%74%70%3a%27%29%26%26%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%6f%73%74%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%2d%68%65%6c%70%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29%29%7b%7d%65%6c%73%65%28%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%72%65%66%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%6d%6f%6e%73%74%65%72%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29'))()
```

any idea on how to decode this?

Comment: Type the strings into the JS console. The first one is "constructor"

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a string and print that out:

```
> "['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']"
  "['constructor']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last "()" and copy/paste the code in the web console of your browser (Ctrl+Shift+K with Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+J with Chrome).

It outputs:

```
(function anonymous() {
if(~location.protocol.indexOf('http:')&&~location.host.indexOf('template-help.com')){}else(location.href='http://templatemonster.com')
})
```